# Composer View in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to create a composer view in laravel 5.1

This is my AppServiceProvider:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{

    view()->composer('layouts.dashboard', function ($view) {
    dd($view);
    }
    );
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```

It gives me :

```
View {#486 ▼
#factory: Factory {#107 ▶}
#engine: CompilerEngine {#382 ▶}
#view: "layouts.dashboard"
#data: array:9 [▼
  "obLevel" => 0
  "__env" => Factory {#107 ▶}
  "app" => Application {#2 ▶}
  "errors" => ViewErrorBag {#322 ▶}
  "currentModelName" => "Torneo"
  "modelPlural" => "Torneos"
  "levels" => Collection {#383 ▶}
  "categories" => Collection {#390 ▶}
  "tournament" => Tournament {#379 ▶}
]
#path:     " /Users/Julien/laravel/resources/views/layouts/dashboard.blade.php"  
 }
```

Now, I need to access currentModelName.

I tried `$view->data` or `$view->data->currentModelName` but it returns `null`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is :

```
$view->currentModelName;
```